# Why vscode's logs folder size is more then ~110GB?

Tags: logging, visual-studio-code, storage

[image: Image of storage analyser]

Here, i have been using Ubuntu continuously since last 1 or 1.5 months but i don't understand why is it this much space required for just log files ?

Comment: have you looked in the files and see if they are related to VSC

Comment: yes it's ts server's log

Comment: what is `ts server`? If you mean the typescript compiler than look if there is a tsconfig.json option to remove logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it was issue of my settings for ts server. it was before,

```
  "typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,
  "typescript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
  "typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true, <---- this
  "typescript.tsserver.maxTsServerMemory": 4096,
  "javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
  "workbench.editor.closeOnFileDelete": true,
  "workbench.editor.limit.enabled": true,
  "Workbench.editor.limit.value": 6,
  "typescript.tsserver.log": "verbose" <----- due to this my log file of vscode was exceed 115GB
```

Due to this my cpu uses increased and also size of ts server's logs was increased.

Solution:
I have changed my setting into,

```
  "typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": false,
  "typescript.tsserver.maxTsServerMemory": 512,
  "typescript.tsserver.log": "off"
```

Now it's working fine.

Comment: Brilliant! This helped a ton